# How can I test Web socket project in SoapUI?

Tags: tomcat, websocket, soapui

I have a url for my websocket service as

```
wss://[HOST_NAME]:8443/TestWebSocket-1.0.0/websocket/9903/DISP/1
```

If I am trying to add this URL to the rest project in SoapUI, Its throws an `invalid protocol,Enter Http/Https` error.

So I can access this web socket URL in SoapUI ?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [soapui-websocket-transport](https://github.com/pbielicki/soapui-websocket-transport) prototype I started. soapUI does not support WebSockets out of the box.

Comment: This project referred do apparently doesn't support WSS (secured) only WS (unsecured). Anyone know of a SOAPUI plugin that supports WSS also?

Comment: I'm getting an error also: ... ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.RequestTransportRegistr‌​y$MissingTransportEx‌​ception: Missing transport for protocol [ws]], see error log for details

Answer (score 0):

according to this there's a plugin that will support it.
https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/Is-there-a-plan-to-support-Websocket-WS-and-WSS-conenction-in/td-p/121244

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)